# Unable to insert or retrieve data's into room where the entity has a list in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I am using room for the first time for my project in Kotlin. I have a Pojo class in which the structure is little complicated. This is my data class which i used:

```
data class CompletedTripListResponse(
    val StatusCode: Int,
    val StatusType: Boolean,
    val `data`: Data,
    val message: String
)

data class Data(
     val current_page: Int,
    val `data`: List<DataList>,
     val first_page_url: String,
     val from: Int,
     val last_page: Int,
     val last_page_url: String,
     val next_page_url: Any,
     val path: String,
     val per_page: Int,
     val prev_page_url: Any,
     val to: Int,
     val total: Int
)

@Entity(tableName = "complete_trip_list_table")
@TypeConverters(ProductTypeConverters::class)
data class DataList(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Int,
    var first_name: String = "",
    var gender_name: String= "",
    var phone_number: String= "",
    var trip_base_rate: Int,
    var trip_date: String= "",
    var trip_destination: String= "",
    var trip_id: Int,
    var trip_invoice: String= "",
    var trip_origin: String= "",
    var trip_time: String= ""
)
```

In this data class i want to insert only values of Datalist into my room database. This is my Dao class

```
@Dao
public interface CompletedTripListDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = REPLACE)
    @JvmSuppressWildcards
    fun insert(item: List<DataList>)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM complete_trip_list_table")
    @JvmSuppressWildcards
    fun load(): LiveData<List<DataList>>

    @Query("SELECT COUNT(*) from complete_trip_list_table")
     fun getCount(): LiveData<Int>
}
```

I am getting count as one but I am unable to get the result even i cannot understand is it inserted or not or the procedure which I followed is correct or not, whether the entity I declared is correct i know I am missing something I went through many online site an even in stack overflow I can find details of only simple insertion not of list data's. Please help me out. The out put of my Api which i have to insert is

```
[DataList(id=0, first_name=amil sj, gender_name=Male, phone_number=9846893375, trip_base_rate=250, trip_date=2020-11-25, trip_destination=Bangalore, Karnataka, India, trip_id=62, trip_invoice=INV-1209729, trip_origin=Airport Rd, Chacka, Thiruvananthapuram, Kerala 695008, India, trip_time=18:45:00)]
```